# How to merge array elements with token merging ## operator???

Tags: c

I want to merge 3, 7, 1 to get 371. I want to know how to merge it???

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
int a[] ={3, 7, 1};
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: what you mean??

Comment: I mean what have you tried to get this done and what problem you face.

Comment: He means *Did you try anything?*

Comment: @AmanWarudkar This is not a 'please do my homework' forum. Show what you tried and explain where your problems are.

Comment: Just think! You have three Integers and want to get one. What could you do, step by step, to achieve this goal. This is what programming is about: Finding structured solutions!

Comment: Token merging is done by the processor ... who doesn't know anything about your array. It just see tokens (and macros).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try something like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int a[] ={3, 7, 1};
    int i, result = 0;

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
        result += a[i] * pow(10, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])-i-1);

    printf("result %d\n", result);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: How can I merge it with token merging ## operator

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than "merge", you want to convert array into an integer value, just like join operation that we see in Java variants. You can easily achieve this by iterating over the array :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int joinArray(int a[], int N) {
  int i, res = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    res = res*10 + a[i];
  return res; 
}

int main() {
  int a[] = {3, 7, 1};
  printf("merged res : %d\n", joinArray(a, 3));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ROHAN. now I can proceed to continue with my PROGRAM.